# How to solve elementary algebraic inequalities from Alan Schoenfeld's book

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I am reading Alan Schoenfeld's problem solving book to learn more about the psychology of problem solving. At the same time I am attempting some of the questions in his book.

One question that I'm having trouble working through is

Suppose you are given the positive numbers $p,q,r,s$ Prove that:

$(p^2 + 1)(q^2 + 1)(r^2 + 1)(s^2 + 1) \geq 16 pqrs$

How do I go about solving this? I have tried multiplying out the LHS, looking to see if a modification to both sides will lead to some clever factorisation. I have considered doing case work breaking it down to if $p,q,r,s \geq 1$ and $p,q,r,s < 1$

Is there a specific factorisation trick I do not know that is the key to solving this? In general what is a smart way of going about this problem?

Comment: Divide the variables and you can observe that it is enough to prove that $p^2+1 \ge 2p$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
2p \leq (1+p^2)
\end{align}
likewise for the other variables then your inequality follows immediately by multiplying everything together.

Edit: To see the above inequality, we start with the observation that
\begin{align}
1+p^2-2p=(1-p)^2\geq 0.
\end{align}